# Capacitors as Energy Wasting?

Tags: electricity, capacitance

I am reading a lot of articles about capacitors as the energy storage.
Let's consider simple circuitry which contain the battery and capacitor in series.

The energy flow from the battery will be $E=\int dt\,UI$.
We have a serial circuit here and the current is the same at every point of the circuitry (battery and capacitor currents are equal).

The battery voltage is constant and the value of $\int dt\,I$ is equal to the capacitor's charge. Therefore the energy we spent is equals to $CU^2$ (as $Q=CU$).

The known expression for energy stored in capacitor indicate exactly half of that.

We just wasted half of the energy during the charge of capacitor.

In case of serial resistance, the half of the energy will dissipate as heat.
Where it will go in case of zero resistance absolutely not clear.

The question here: why people still working on capacitor based energy storage?
If every car in the world will run on capacitor, the energy consumption will be doubled.

Comment: If the voltage across the capacitor was $U$ all along, then by $Q = CU$ it would follow, that $I= \dot Q = 0$.

Comment: During charging 1/2 the energy is dissipated. There is no "lossless" wire if the current is infinitely large which will happen when you connect the battery to the discharged capacitor.   But if you charge from a variable voltage source just above the capacitor's actual voltage then the dissipated energy can be made arbitrarily small. This is quite similar to the thermodynamic concept of "quasistatic" process.

Comment: Your title is misleading.  A capacitor doesn't "waste" (i.e., dissipate) any energy.  It's the resistance in the circuit that charges the capacitor that's to blame.  You are describing an inherent problem in all linear power supplies/chargers/amplifiers, etc.  That is why switching-mode power supplies/chargers/amplifiers are greatly preferred.